# Isabelle Real Datatype - Malformed definition: Non-constructor pattern not allowed in sequential mode

Tags: isabelle

I am creating a function of the form

> y(t+h) = y(t) + h/y(t)
>
> where y(0) = 1

`fun y :: "real ⇒ real" where
  "y 0 = Suc(0)"|
  "y(t+h) = y(t) + h*(1/y(t))"`

Unfortunately, I am getting an error

> Malformed definition: Non-constructor pattern not allowed in sequential mode.
>
> y 0 = real (Suc 0)

Googling showed me that I am not adhering to some constructor pattern of real datatype but I am not able to find what the pattern is and how I should change my function.

Answer (score 0):

Real numbers are not an algebraic datatype, so you can't pattern match on them with `fun`. You have to use either ‘normal’ equational definitions or some of the more advanced features of the function package, but that also makes things more difficult since you have to prove some well-definedness properties yourself.

Also, the `Suc 0` on the right-hand side is a natural number, not a real number. (just write `1` instead)

However, the biggest problem with your definition is that the way you have written it down is too informal. I don't understand what it means even informally.

- What assumptions do you have about `h`?
- For what `t` should that second equation be valid?
- What happens when you put in a negative value for `t`? (the way you've written it: non-termination)
- What happens when `0 < t < h`?

Once you have a mathematically precise specification for the function you want to define, you can probably write it down without too much of a headache with the `function` command

Comment: The actual eqn is dy/dt = 1/y. I am trying to use Euler method to find a solution. So the eqn becomes (y(t+h) - y(t))/h = 1/y. h is a very small number. h<<t and t>0

Comment: Well, still, you have to answer that question: you are trying to define a function `y` and `h` is some small positive real number. What is the value of `y` for `t ∈ (0;h)`?

Comment: Is it possible to define an increment step h, which makes (t+h) the next smallest value possible?

Comment: Sorry, but seeing as I don't even understand what the function `y` should be on an abstract mathematical level, I cannot really help you with getting that into Isabelle. As for Euler's method, I would say it does not define an entire function y: ℝ→ℝ, but rather a sequence of numbers (i.e. y: ℕ→ℝ) of successive approximations of the actual function at time points 0, h, 2h, 3h, etc. That you can write in Isabelle either as a function `nat ⇒ real` or a `real stream`, but the former will probably be more suitable in this case.