# Verifying Simulink Models in Isabelle

Tags: simulink, isabelle

I am trying to capture a Simulink Model in Isabelle. The goal is to check if the simulation output can be verified in Isabelle.

[image: Simulink Model]

[image: Simulation]

The model represents the ODE

> dy/dt =  1/y(t)

I want to prove a lemma that states that when t>5 then y(t) > 3.

To prove this, first I have to find y(t) and express it in Isabelle. To solve the ODE I use one Numerical Approximation method, the Euler Method.

> dy/dt = (y(t+h) - y(t))/h where h << t
>
> y(t+h) = y(t) + h*(1/y(t))

I am unable to represent the above function in Isabelle as t and h are real numbers and I don't have a clue on how to represent this.

I want the function definition to be of this sort

`fun y :: "real ⇒ real" where
  "y 0 = 1"|
  "y(t+h) = y(t) + h*(1/y(t))"`

But I am dealing with Malformed definition: Non-constructor pattern not allowed in sequential mode which I don't understand at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Isabelle Real Datatype - Malformed definition: Non-constructor pattern not allowed in sequential mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238481/isabelle-real-datatype-malformed-definition-non-constructor-pattern-not-allow)

Comment: Lol that's my question

Comment: … which is why I'm surprised that you're asking it again